# Compare 2 tables based on range values

Tags: sql

We have big transaction tables, it has all the values (including duplicates),  need to eliminate the duplicate values based on other table values.

Table A (Transaction table) has Store, Date, Index , Etc values
Table B maintain the Index ranges, it has Store, Date, Index Begin, Index End etc.

Based on Store, Date need to compare index from table A with Table B (Table B has index Range values), eliminate the ranges of index values from Table A, so I can avoid duplicate values.

If the given index is not in range of Index Begin and Index End, I can keep that. Indexes range starts from 1. But I need to keep 1, it's a header record.

It has to check from Index 2 onwards. If you could please help with SQL statement that would be great.

Tried with few statements, did not work.

Need to eliminate duplicate records based on Index ranges from table B

Comment: I downvoted because ["It's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) and [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) and [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL. Then **[EDIT]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the missing information as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), do **NOT** post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the duplicates use the key word DISTINCT after SELECT, so SELECT DISTINCT. You'll need to write a JOIN statement that compares the two tables based on the common value.

I assume you already have a query so I won't write one unless you comment needing help:)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, Its not distinct values always. Check has to be done against table B index ranges then eliminate those values based on check. If there are multiple index values for 2 in Table A, but if that entry in table B, i would keep it.  If the Index values are present in Table B between Indexbegin and Indexend then i would eliminate that from table A. Please help with SQL. Many thanks.